# Deserializing Json into objects

Tags: c#, json, json.net

So the app I'm currently working with is going to be doing a lot of requests that all return json, would it be appropriate to create a class that holds the properties for each specific request thats going to return the json that can be converted into the properties of that class?

For example, say I have 2 requests, one that returns a firstname, a surname and a job role, and I have another request that returns a business name, business location and business postcode, would it be OK to do:

```
class BusinessRetrieval {
  public string BusinessLocation{ get; set; }
  public string BusinessPostCode { get; set; }
}

class EmployeeRetrieval {
  public string Firstname { get; set; }
  public string Surname { get; set;}
  public string Postcode { get; set; }
}
```

So now I have 2 classes that outline the properties that are going to be sent back once the request is made, now is it OK to just do:

```
BusinessRetrieval business = (BusinessRetrieval)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(businessResponse, typeof(BusinessRetrieval));
EmployeeRetrieval employee = (EmployeeRetrieval)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(employeeResponse, typeof(EmployeeRetrieval));
```

What I'm asking here is this an OK to go around doing this? I'm going to be dealing with a lot of requests (10-15) and I plan on making a class for each that outline the properties that each response will give back, I feel as if this would be a nice way to structure it.

Is this OK?

Comment: Are you asking for approval? You should be more specific about what your concerns are.

Comment: Yes. I want to know if this is an OK thing to do.

Comment: "OK" is subjective. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is the only reasonable way to handle it to make your code type safe.
Though you cannot cast the result of the non generic `DeserializeObject` to the type of your choice - it will throw an Exception.
Instead use the Generic version of DeserializeObject:

```
BusinessRetrieval business = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BusinessRetrieval>(businessResponse);
EmployeeRetrieval employee = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmployeeRetrieval>(employeeResponse);
```

Comment: Oh yes this is much better.

Originally I was doing:

EmployeeRetrieval employee = (EmployeeRetrieval)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(employeeResponse, typeof(EmployeeRetrieval));

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not only okay to do, I think it would be a best practice so you can pass that object through any methods without any problems.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Thank you for your input